# Is there such a thing as laminar-turbulent transition in free flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, turbulence

Free flow in the sense of "without any objects or obstacles influencing the flow". High altitude wind or ocean currents could probably be real-world examples.

There is the well known experiment where color is added to a water flow inside a transparent pipe, and starting from a certain velocity, the color rips apart chaotically, visualizing the transition of laminar to turbulent flow.

Does this effect have something to do with the influence of the pipe walls on the flow? Or would it act similar if the pipe weren't there at all?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an infinite volume of air all traveling a high speed at uniform velocity, it is the same as if the air was at rest. It is just a change of frame of reference.

Turbulence is caused by differencs in air speed from one place to another. These are often caused by pipe walls because there is a non-moving boundary layer along the wall.